# Modifying Django pre_/post_save data during one method.save()

Tags: django, signals

Hi I'm writing an hardware inventory application, and I'd like to log each time a new part get's entered in, along with any future status changes/updates.

models

```
class Part(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(PartType, blank=False)
    bar_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, blank=False)

class PartLog(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, blank=False)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now_add=True)
    old_status = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name='old_status_related', blank=False)
    new_status = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name='new_status_related', blank=False)

class Status(models.Model):
    current_status = (
     ("EN", "Entered Database"),
     ("CO", "Checked out"),
     ("CI", "Checked in"),
     ("RM", "Returned for RMA"),
     ("IU", "Currently in use"),     
                    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=current_status)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.status)
```

signals

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Part)
def add_to_partLog(sender, instance, signal, created, *args, **kwargs):

    if created:
        print "Since a new entry has been created, setting old and new status for partlog entry!"
        # Automatically changing status from Entered state to Checked In state
        # Part Table
        instance.status=Status(3)
        instance.save()

        # Setting Old and New status for the first (new) partLog entry for the new added part
        # Part Log table
        oldStatus = Status(1)
        newStatus = Status(3)
        partobj = Part.objects.get(id=instance.pk)
        PartLog.objects.create(part=partobj,old_status=oldStatus, new_status=newStatus)
    else:
        print "Entry already exists!"
        # Retreiving the old status of the Part() record

        oldStatus = ???
        newStatus = instance.status
        partobj = Part.objects.get(id=instance.pk)
        PartLog.objects.create(part=partobj,old_status=oldStatus,new_status=newStatus)
```

views

```
def check_in_part(request):
    err_list=[]
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PartForm(request.POST)
        print "form object is created."
        if form.is_valid():  
            form.save()  
            return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/current_count/')    
    else:        
        form = PartForm(initial={'status':1L})
    return render(request,'add_part.html',{
                                           'title':'Add Item',
                                           'form':form
                                           })


# Checking out a part    
def check_out_part(request):
   errlst = []
   c = {}
   c.update(csrf(request))
   # ADD check against DB with the appropriate status "CO" or 3
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ModifyPartForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           bar_code_form = form.cleaned_data['bar_code']
           try:
               bar_code_model= Part.objects.get(bar_code=bar_code_form)
           except Part.DoesNotExist:
               #FIXME: need to get errlst to user
               errlst.append("Part with bar_code %s does not exist." % bar_code_form)
           else:
                #bar_code_model.check_out()
               bar_code_model.status_id=2L
               bar_code_model.save()
               return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/current_count/')
   else:
       form = ModifyPartForm()
       # Adding default status to Check Out or "CO"
   return render(request, 'remove_part.html',{
                                           'title':'Remove Item',
                                           'form': form,
                                           'errors': errlst,
                                           })
```

The problem lies within the else clause in the signals. The first part of the if works just fine. **I'm not sure how to access the "status" before it was saved and use it on the post save. ** Right now in one view, when I check_in a new part I'm making the initial status "EN", and then changing it automatically to "CI". Right now for the check_out view I'd just like to search for the Part() with the barcode, and update and log both tables appropriately.Eventually I'd like to be able to choose between other statuses that are listed in a drop down menu, but that's for later =)

Comment: Are you sure the signature is right on that `post_save`? I thought the 3rd arg is `created`. What is the `signal` arg?

Comment: I'm not sure that it matter the order of the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up caching the status object here is my answer.

```
#Signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Part)
def log_entry(sender, instance, created, raw, *args, **kwargs):
    # Using the statuses from the above method to create a PartLog entry. 
    newStatus = instance.status

    if not created:
        # Get old status from current state
        oldStatus = instance._state.old_status
        PartLog.objects.create(part=instance,
                               old_status=oldStatus,
                               new_status=instance.status)
        instance._state.old_status = newStatus
    else:
        PartLog.objects.create(part=instance, old_status=Status(1), new_status=Status(3))

#Models.py

class Part(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(PartType, blank=False)
    bar_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, blank=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Part, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Caching the existing Part object's status
        if self.pk:
            self._state.old_status = self.status

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.bar_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to know the previous value of the field at the `post_save` signal stage because the model doesn't track pre-post values of the fields. You have two options:

1. Cache the status field in the `__init__()` of the model and possibly the new value on `save()` and check those in your `post_save`
2. Do a database lookup of the current value in a `pre_save` signal and cache it on the object so it can be referenced after the save has completed.

I tend to use the first approach and avoid the database query. You have to be aware that caching the field ahead of time means you can no longer defer that field in a query since you are explicitly accessing it in the `__init__`

It might look something like this:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Part, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._status_old_cached = self.status 


@receiver(post_save, sender=Part)
def add_to_partLog(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    else:
        oldStatus = instance._status_old_cached
```

Because this will force a lookup on the field right away, make sure you `select_related` on this field in your query ahead of time:

```
Part.objects.select_related('status').all()
```

If you don't actually need the status object, and just want the `id`, then it will probably save you the lookup since the model actually saves the id:

```
self._status_id_old_cached = self.status_id
```

Comment: I'd like to go with route 1. by caching the status field in the Part model. But now I've got both clauses of my if statement executing in my signals. It still saves the record in the Part table though which I find strange...

Comment: Also, the second part of your comment I don't understand. I guess let me ask does the caching force a lookup on the field right away?

Comment: Are you still using the same arguments from your example or are you using mine with `created` as the 3rd parameter? Also, yes thats what I was referring to... accessing `self.status` from the init will force a lookup if its not already `selected_related` which is why I was suggesting you could just use the id if thats all you needed.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense, thanks for the clarification. But yes, my receiver function is just using sender, instance, & created. It blows up on the create() on the PartLog in the else statement in signals.py. It still saves it to the database though. I'm going to try moving the PartLog outside of the if else statement.

Comment: I believe this error is somewhat unrelated. It comes from your view where you take values from the form. Then you call save on it, but there was a None value for `old_status` so it fails.